# Executing manage.py in Django Management Shell

Tags: django, django-migrations

I am attempting to execute manage.py using Django Management Shell in Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise.

[Django Management Shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7A9Y.png)

The purpose of this was to run a Django Migration to a particular database. I have installed database routers to point individual models to individual databases according to read/write.

I have Python 3.6 installed and have been able to execute python.exe using command prompt. However, when I try to connect to manage.py which is hosted on a UNC path, the same error occurs - invalid syntax.

Please can someone advise as to how to execute this migration to a particular database?

Best wishes,

Neil

Answer (score 0):

Commands like

```
python manage.py migrate 
python manage.py makemigrations 
python manage.py ...
```

need to be executed from terminal not from shell.

Django shell is python shell configured for your Django project. There you can import and play around with the code, inspect classes, try out methods. It can be started also from terminal using command:

```
python manage.py shell
```